# Image source converter with DependencyProperty

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, converters, dependency-properties

I'm working on a WP8 MVVM app and i'm stuck at a binding problem.

I have this XAML code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<local:CurrentCategorySourceConverter x:Key="CurrentCategorySourceConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and

```
<Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
       Name="MovieThumbnail" 
       Stretch="Fill"
       Width="130" Height="195"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center">
       <Image.Source>
             <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=Image120x170,Converter={StaticResource CurrentCategorySourceConverter}}"
                          CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
       </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

My converter:

```
public class CurrentCategorySourceConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
    {
        public bool isCurrent
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(CurrentCategoryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CurrentCategoryProperty, value); }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty CurrentCategoryProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("isCurrent",
                                        typeof(bool),
                                        typeof(CurrentCategorySourceConverter),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && isCurrent == true)
            {
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that i can't bind the isCurrent property of the converter in the XAML, because the datacontext is null when the usercontrol is created.

The following code results in a XAML exception:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<local:CurrentCategorySourceConverter x:Key="CurrentCategorySourceConverter"
                                      isCurrent="{Binding currentCategory}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

So i'm trying to set the binding in the code when the datacontext exists:

```
this.model = this.DataContext as CategoryPageContentViewModelApp;
converter = this.Resources["CurrentCategorySourceConverter"] as CurrentCategorySourceConverter;
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = this.model;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("currentCategory");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(converter,CurrentCategorySourceConverter.CurrentCategoryProperty, binding);
```

The problem is that when i raise a property change from the model on the currentCategory, the converter and the source of the image does not change.

This is what i'm trying to achieve with the converter: the source of the image should be a local value when the category is the current one and another value when the category is not current. I'm trying to use the dependency property and raising the change event so that it automatically changes when the category "current" state changes. I searched on the internet and in my undestanding it should work but i'm certainly doing something wrong as it does not work. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Catalin

**EDIT:**

Ok, so i made a binding reflector, and the converter parameter is now binding. But the ting is that it's not updating realtime.

I have a pivot, and a user control in each item, which contains a lot of images. To reduce the memory usage, i made this converter to make it show images only for the current pivot item. But when the binded bool for category is set to true, the source of the images is now updated unless i reload the page. Though the changes to the two properties , source and bool for current categories are reflected on each other.

Comment: Did you try setting the DataContext before the call to InitializeComponenet() within the constructor?

Comment: Yes. But my user control is actually in an pivot item of a pivot that has the ItemsSource an observable collection. So the datacontext is just inherited from there. I can access the datacontext only after the user control is loaded.

Comment: A multibinding converter would be very useful but as i understand it's not usable on WP8.

Comment: I made it work another way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332835/changepropertyaction-on-image-control-in-longlistselector-item-template/